# Is there a way to print a new-line when using <Message...>?

Tags: msbuild

I wanna write `<Message Text="Line1\nLine2\nLine3" />` but \n seems not to be working. What should I replace \n with?

(I read in the books they said that to print @ and % we use %40 and %25, so I guess the should be a number for the new-line).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

CR = 0x0D or 13

LF = 0x0A or 10

Comment: Thanks DaveE. 
I try <Message Text="a%0Abb" />. It works and print out:
a
bb

Thank you.

Comment: What a lazy answer, why not include a full example, the answer is actually contained in OP's comment (and other answer).

Comment: Well, i *could* have done the "throw it up and see if it sticks" answer, or i could explain the values necessary to achieve what the poster wanted and let them apply it themselves.

Answer (score 46):

Try this:
`<Message Text="Line1%0aLine2%0aLine3%0a" />`

Comment: This is ironically the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the multiline message in a property (in the example below called `MyMultilineMessage`) and then use that property in the message text. (Works at least with MSBuild for VisualStudio 2019)

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MyMultilineMessage>

Lorum ipsum...
      </MyMultilineMessage>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Importance="High" Text="$(MyMultilineMessage)"/>
```

This also works for `Error` elements as well.

**Edit:** Modified XML example above after comment about missing `PropertyGroup`.

Comment: You need to use "PropertyGroup", not "Property"

Comment: It is still wrong, sorry. Use:
`<PropertyGroup>
  <MyMultilineMessage>
    ....
  </MyMultilineMessage>
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: You are right! Should be fixed now. Thank you for spotting this! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the lines into an item group

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Lines Include="Line 1 " />
      <Lines Include="Line 2 " />
      <Lines Include="Line 3 " />
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="%(Lines.Identity)"/>
```