# In MSBuild, how to split a string on endlines?

Tags: string, split, msbuild

Other questions  ([MSBUILD Splitting text file into lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963853/msbuild-splitting-text-file-into-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1)) mention implementation-specific alternatives, but none seem to directly address how to split a simple string property into an item group based on endlines.

How can you do this? Attempts that didn't work:

- `<ItemGroup>
     <SplitLines Include="$(SourceString.Split('\r\n'))" />
  </ItemGroup>`: *(splits on `'r'` or `'n'`)*
- `<ItemGroup>
     <SplitLines Include="$(SourceString.Split('%0A%0D'))" />
  </ItemGroup>`: *(doesn't split at all)*

In case you're curious: `SourceString` is the output of an `Exec` command that needs splitting, so `ReadLinesFromFile` isn't an option. It can't output to an intermediary file because file systems are slow and this needs to be used by build processes that care about file operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using property functions is the way to go and you can search for sulutions using e.g. 'C# split string lines' in your search engine of choice, then translate the answer. This comes up with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508203/best-way-to-split-string-into-lines) and the Regex.Split method is the easiest to implement:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SplitLines Include="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Split(`$(SourceString)`, `\r\n|\r|\n`))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks!